# FortRabbit - performance - image transforms

Tags: image-transforms

Anybody else have problems with image transforms on FortRabbit?

They sent me this article as some background - https://blog.fortrabbit.com/imagemagick-issues

I was using the light level of hosting (https://www.fortrabbit.com/pricing) but encountered corrupted/slow transform images. I upgraded to 'Standard' and it seemed to be a bit better but still slow.

The transforms I had were only going from 1.5MB down to max 2000x2000 and there were 10's of them no 100's

I am new to Craft so not sure if this is a common thing, if other hosts have the same problem or if I just need to upgrade my hosting level on FortRabbit or another host?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Frank from fortrabbit here. We are currently (2019-06) looking into increased reports on that matter. Please post a support request, if you encounter that currently. From our point of view, something has changed from IM 6 to IM 7. We have applied a policy fix back in March. See also here: https://blog.fortrabbit.com/imagemagick-issues